# How to scope a CSS file by adding parent and prepended selector to all style rules with Less?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to scope a library's CSS to specific elements / components. I was able to do add a parent selector pretty easily with Less like this:

```
.scopingSelector {
  @import (less) './original.css';
}
```

This adds my scopingSelector as a parent to all rules found in the original file. Ouput something like:

```
.scopingSelector .original {
  ... css rules
}
```

However, I also want to add a selector that applies scoped rules if my scoping selector and the original selector are on the same element, not just children. The desired output would look like this:

```
.scopingSelector .original,
.scopingSelector.original {
  ... css rules
}
```

... and this is where I'm hitting a wall :) I do not need to use Less for this but it seems like it is the right tool for the job. It should work for all types of style rules (ie: both classes and elements) in the original file.

Can this be done easily with Less or another language that compiles down to CSS?

note: I found [this question from a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573812/scoping-css-prepend-selector-with-less) which looked promising at first. However, the proposed answer (`&.originalClass:extend(.scopingSelector .originalClass all) {}`) only works when you know which selector you would like to scope in this way. I'd like to blanket apply it to every rule from an imported CSS file.

[:extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) seems promising, but I've been playing around with it for a while without any luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Does prepending `&` to the included file's selector not work? When you do this, `.original {}` in your include file it essentially does `& .original {}` (notice the space between `&` and `.`). Try `&.original {}` in your include file.

Comment: Do you mean by modifying the original file? I'd like to avoid doing this. For context, it has about ~30k lines of CSS. I'd also like to use this for quick and dirty scoping of other CSS if necessary.

...I may have misunderstood you, apologies if so! If I do `&.scopingSelector { import ... }` it spits out the same CSS.

Comment: Yes, I meant the original file. I don't know how you're going to do this without modifying the original file or listing all the selectors in the original file and using the approach from the linked SO post.